# Scroll view does not respond

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

Works great for portrait mode. If I go on landscape mode I have my activity drawn in the center of screen which leaves blank screen on both left and right side.
If I drag by keeping mouse on views (i.e. center)the scroll takes effect.
If I drag on empty right side no scrolling ? why ?

[image: Attaching] the image

posting my layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/enter_pin_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/enter_pin_header_layout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/pin_inset_region_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/pin_inset_region_height"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
```

Comment: It looks like you're hard coding the sizes of the views. The scrollview doesn't exist in that black area, so it will never work like you want it.

Answer (score 0):

set your scroll view's width to **fillparent** not *wrap content*

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your ScrollView's width is set to `wrap_content` and thus, touch events outside of the dial pad are not taking any effect.

You can fix this by changing,

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    ... />
```

to,

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    ... />
```

Comment: Thanks all for your input, That was my first attempt to resolve this issue. but no luck I have my scroll view width set to match parent. please view my layout in edited question

Answer (score 0):

If every view is stored in the ScrollView, why not remove the RelativeLayout ? Have directly :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/enter_pin_scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/enter_pin_header_layout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/pin_inset_region_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/pin_inset_region_height"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
```

If you want to keep it :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Set the layout_height to fill_parent.